# paper on arXiv but not on Google scholar

Tags: arxiv, google-scholar

My paper has been put on the arXiv very recently (approx. a week ago) and to the journal, and currently is under refereeing process.

I would like to ask how long it takes for Google Scholar to recognise the paper and associate it to my account. The paper does not even appear yet on Google scholar.